# Find the values of A and b for which the planes are parallel

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing a problem in Linear Algebra where I have to find all values of let's say A and B for which the planes are parallel.

\begin{align}
    2x - 4Ay + 2Bz &= 2 + 2B \tag1\\
    3Bx - 3y + 3z &= 3 + 3B \tag2
\end{align}

First I divided the (1) equation by 2 and (2) equation by 3, then I extracted the plane vector from both planes and two planes are parallel if their vector planes are the same (linear or co-linear) and I got:

```
1 / B = 2A / 1 = B / 1 = 1+B / 1+B
```

From this we can clearly see that B = 1 and A = 1/2,
But the professor said that there are more A and B for which these planes are parallel but I don't see how can I find them, can anybody give me  a hint how to find the other solutions ?!

Comment: How about $B=-1, A=-\frac{1}{2}$? Actually, if you have $\frac{1}{B}=\frac{B}{1}$, this means $B^2=1$, i.e. $B=\pm1$.

Comment: @user8734617 Yep, actually that's a solution, too. Maybe this is the piece I have missed!

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Two planes
$$Px+Qy+Rz=S$$
$$Tx+Uy+Vz=W$$
are parallel if and only if there exists some real number $k$ such that
$$k(P,Q,R)=(T,U,V)$$

If, furthermore, $kS=W$, they are the same plane.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

\begin{align}
    2x - 4Ay + 2Bz &= 2 + 2B \tag1\\
    3Bx - 3y + 3z &= 3 + 3B \tag2
\end{align}

are parallel if and only if normal vectors

$$\vec n_1=(2,-4A,2B) \quad \vec n_2=(3B,-3,3)$$

are multiple that is $\vec n_2=k\cdot \vec n_1$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$

- $3B=2k$
- $-3=-4Ak$
- $3=2kB$

Solving the system we find $k=\frac32$ and then

- $A=\frac12$
- $B=1$

Comment: So you are saying that A and B have only one solution, right?

Comment: In general the plane $ax+by+cz=d$ has normal $n=(a,b,c)$

Comment: $k=-\frac32$ also leads to a solution.

Comment: @amd yes you are right since if $n_1$ is multiple of $k n_2$ it is also multiple of $-kn_2$, but there are not other solutions in this case

Comment: There are exactly two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The planes will be parallel when their normals are parallel, i.e., that $(2,-4A,2B) = k(3B,-3,3)$ for some scalar $k$. You can avoid introducing the extra variable $k$ by taking advantage of working in $\mathbb R^3$: the parallel condition can be expressed as $(2,-4A,2B) \times (3B,-3,3)=0$, which will give you three equations in $A$ and $B$ only, namely, $$\begin{align} -12A+6B &= 0 \\ 6B^2-6 &= 0 \\ 12AB-6 &=0. \end{align}$$

Comment: Could you please continue with how to do the multiplication? I am stuck at B + A = 0, but I believe I am probably wrong.